# TypeError: Cannot read property 'interface' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethereum

my init.js file

```
var web3 = require('web3');
fs = require('fs');
solc  = require('solc');

web3 = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
code = fs.readFileSync('kyc.sol').toString();
//contract = web3.eth.compile.solidity(code);
contract = solc.compile(code);

function after2Delay() {
    contractInstance = kycContract.at(deployedContract.address);
    console.log(contractInstance.address);
}

function afterDelay() {
    abiDefinition = JSON.parse(contract.contracts[':kyc'].interface);
    byteCode = contract.contracts[':kyc'].bytecode;
    kycContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition);
    deployedContract = kycContract.new({data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000});
    setTimeout(after2Delay, 3000);
}

setTimeout(afterDelay, 8000);
```

After I run rpc using `ganache-cli` . I run the above code using `node init.js` . I'm getting following error

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath"normalize";var ret=nodeFS["readFileSy
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'interface' of undefined
>       at Timeout.afterDelay [as _onTimeout] (/Users/pc/Documents/Programs/KYC-chain-master/root/init.js:16:59)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5)

I've read it from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29008/cant-compile-contract-pragma-error-and-cannot-read-property-interface-of-un) that the problem could be solved my making contract name same as file name. My contract name and file name are same i.e `kyc`

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide the `contract` object as well?

Comment: People who -ve vote. Please do say the problem with the question. It will help me improve my understanding of stackoverflow usage and standard of the question. Thanks !

Comment: I am not asking for the file, I am asking for `contract` object's value in this line `abiDefinition = JSON.parse(contract.contracts[':kyc'].interface);`

Comment: You've clearly not asked a question about code *you wrote*, but are instead trying to ask here about how to debug a problem in someone else's code.  If you don't have a solid understanding of the code you are trying to fix, how can you help others to understand and troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt When I tried to print the `contract` objects I'm getting `AAssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.` let me check the callback address and will update the question

Comment: @Claies When I took time to understand the code I could correct them by installing correct version of  web3 and solc. So I edited the question to the one that is making some trouble in execution.